# To what viewport do media queries in Shadow DOM elements apply?

Tags: media-queries, web-component

The HTML5 Rocks tutorial on [styling the Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/) doesn't discuss media queries. Since the *shadow boundary* is supposed to provide style encapsulation for free, it would be really neat if @media queries applied to the size of the host element, rather than the viewport of the browser.

This would solve the problem of [media queries being a hack](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/) when in reality we need @element queries, which as of July 2015 exist only as an [abandoned repo on GitHub](https://github.com/tysonmatanich/elementQuery).

Answer (score 4):

Alas, no. The `@media` queries inside the Shadow DOM look at the viewport of the browser, not at the dimensions of the host element.

```js
var root = document.querySelector('div').createShadowRoot();
root.innerHTML = '<style>@media (min-width: 600px) { h3 { color: red; }}</style>' + 
                 '<h3>If this text is not red, you live far in the future</h3>';
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px"><h3>Light DOM</h3></div>
```

This is probably because of the [circularity issues](http://www.xanthir.com/b4VG0) that might ensue if the Shadow DOM element sized itself in a way incompatible with the host.